# How to get unchecked value on lightning tree grid?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightningtreegrid

There is standard behavior on [Lightning tree grid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/example), where when we expand a parent, select a child, then collapse it, the child will be unselected. I am now able to keep the selected child value. Therefore, when I collapse and extend a parent, the child checkbox will be retained.

However, I have an issue when a user unchecks a child checkbox and then collapses the parent. The value is not changed. I have checked the documentation but there is no event or parameter to get the currently selected value.

How do I resolve this?

lwc.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-tree-grid if:false={loadingdata} data-id="grid" columns={columns}
        data={data} key-field="code" onrowselection={handleRowSelection} ontoggle={handleToggle} ontoggleall={handleToggle}>
    </lightning-tree-grid>
</template>
```

lwc.js:

```
selectedrows = []; //currently visible selected checkbox
selectedrowsontoggle = []; //saved checkbox value (saved during collapsing a parent)
bypassrowselection = false;

handleToggle(ev) {
    if(ev.detail.isExpanded) {
        this.setselectedrows();
    }
    else {
        this.selectedrowsontoggle = this.selectedrowsontoggle.concat(this.selectedrows.filter((item) => this.selectedrowsontoggle.indexOf(item) < 0));
        this.bypassrowselection = true;
    }
}

handleRowSelection(ev) {
    if(this.bypassrowselection) {
        this.bypassrowselection = false;
        return;
    }
    const el = this.template.querySelector("lightning-tree-grid[data-id='grid']");
    if(el) {
        let rows = [];
        el.getSelectedRows().forEach((r) => {
            rows.push(r.code);
        });

        // this.selectedrows = [...rows];
        let temp = this.selectedRows.slice(); //saved currently active checkbox for comparison later
        
        if(this.selectedrowsontoggle.concat(rows.filter((item) => this.selectedrowsontoggle.indexOf(item) < 0)).length > this.selectedrows.length)
        {
            //checkbox checked
            this.selectedrows = this.selectedrows.concat(rows.filter((item) => this.selectedrows.indexOf(item) < 0));
        }
        else
        {
            //checkbox unchecked
            let combined = [];
            combined = this.selectedrows.filter(element => rows.includes(element));
            if((rows.length != 0 && combined.length == 0 ))
            {
                //this means selectedrows and rows have no value in common. Combine them.
                combined = this.selectedrows.concat(rows.filter((item) => this.selectedrows.indexOf(item) < 0));
            }

            this.selectedrows = combined;
        }
        
        //NOTE: this is where I attempt to find the unchecked value.
        if(this.temp.length > this.selectedrows.length)
        {
            //something is unchecked and find the unchecked value
            this.temp = this.temp.filter(x => !this.selectedrows.includes(x));
            // this.temp = this.selectedrowsontoggle.filter(x => !this.temp.includes(x));

            let removedvalue = this.temp[0]; //NOTE: I cannot figure out how to find the unchecked value.
            //remove from selectedrows and selectedrowsontoggle
            let index = this.selectedrows.indexOf(removedvalue);
            if (index > -1) {
                this.selectedrows.splice(index, 1);
            }
            index = this.selectedrowsontoggle.indexOf(removedvalue);
            if (index > -1) {
                this.selectedrowsontoggle.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }

        //combine selectedrow with selectedrowontoggle
        this.selectedrows = this.selectedrows.concat(this.selectedrowsontoggle.filter((item) => this.selectedrows.indexOf(item) < 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: did you fix this issue ?